future.batchtools sends an array of incorrect batch scripts
I am using doFuture, future.batchtools, and the foreach function to parallelize some code over 128 CPUs on one node of a HPC that runs on a PBS scheduler. What I would like my code to do is send out one batch script that allocates my tasks over those 128 CPUs. What my code does instead is send out one batch script per task that sets all 128 CPUs on the task, and from what I can see in the logs in ~/.future, it is sending out incorrectly formatted PBS scripts at that.
For the record, I can tell that the tasks are each getting allocated in its own script because I get an email when each task is queued and run, and each ones indicates that all 128 CPUs have been allocated to that task:
PBS Job Id: <ID>
Job Name:   <NAME>
Execution terminated
Exit_status=0
resources_used.cpupercent=34
resources_used.cput=00:00:05
resources_used.mem=172924kb
resources_used.ncpus=128
resources_used.vmem=344632kb
resources_used.walltime=00:00:16
resources_used.x-ncar-cpu-energy=1446
resources_used.x-ncar-energy=4638
resources_used.x-ncar-gpu0-energy=0
resources_used.x-ncar-gpu1-energy=0
resources_used.x-ncar-gpu2-energy=0
resources_used.x-ncar-gpu3-energy=0
resources_used.x-ncar-memory-energy=2119

I also surmise that incorrect batch scripts are getting sent out because I can see the .job file in the subfolder of ~/.future that corresponds to this attempt at running the code. Here is what that .job file looks like:
#!/bin/bash
# A batchtools launch script template for Torque/PBS
#
# Author: Henrik Bengtsson
#PBS -N doFuture-1
#PBS -o <PATH>
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m ae

Rscript -e 'batchtools::doJobCollection("$USER/.future/20240730_114515-rRSERU/doFuture-1_1617075820/jobs/job837f1719a5861dcb9c3d105d8fa76975.rds")'

As you can see here, this job script is missing a bunch of essential information that PBS requires of any batch script, such as walltime and resource specification.
Here is my extremely simplified reprex version of my code that replicates the problem:
library(doFuture)
library(future.batchtools)
registerDoFuture()
plan(list(batchtools_torque, multicore))
y <- foreach(x = 1:4, y = 1:10) %dopar% {
  z <- x + y
  sqrt(z)
}

Here is my batchtools.torque.tmpl file:
#!/bin/bash
## Project code
#PBS -A $CODE
## Job name
#PBS -N $NAME
## Queue
#PBS -q main
## Output log format
#PBS -j oe
## Email notifications
#PBS -m abe
## How long do I want on the nodes
#PBS -l $WALLTIME
## Computational allocation
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=128:mpiprocs=128

### Set temp to scratch
export TMPDIR=${SCRATCH}/${USER}/temp && mkdir -p $TMPDIR

# Load modules to match compile-time environment
module purge
module load gcc/13.2.0 conda/latest

# Activate conda environment
conda activate sim

# Run script
Rscript -e 'library(batchtools); batchtools::doJobCollection("<%= uri %>")'

